# How to loop code until it works in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I have a long code, here is a small excerpt from it. You constantly need to find elements, insert data and click buttons. Sometimes something fails to load and errors pop up. Is it possible to have Python try these commands until it succeeds? I can't use

```
time.sleep()
```

with a long delay as it will greatly increase the execution time and even that doesn't always help(

```
start = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "SELECTOR")
start.click()
time.sleep(1)

start2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "SELECTOR")
start2.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: why don't use `try except ` statements?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Sometimes something fails to load and errors pop up. Is it possible to have Python try these commands until it succeeds?" Well, first off, *why should it ever succeed* if you simply keep trying in the same way? "...and even that doesn't always help" - well, in that case you first need to **think about why it doesn't**, and understand the underlying problem.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I thought there would be another option, because you will have to use try except everywhere

Comment: That said, you have already tagged the question with `loops`, and the obvious answer is to write a loop; I don't see where you're stuck? I assume you have heard of both `for` and `while` loops; which seems more appropriate here? Then, think about: **how can the program know** whether the click succeeded or not?

Comment: Please also read [ask] and [mre], and make sure the problem is clear and evident.

Comment: Python can't always find the element and throws the error "Message: no such element"

Comment: Before clicking, the program looks for the element, so it understands if the element was found successfully

Comment: And the "time.sleep()" command does not always help, because the page load speed is always different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a method that waits for an element to be clickable first, then you can set a default timeout, and then use that, as shown below with this partial code example that uses `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def wait_for_element_clickable(
    driver, selector, by="css selector", timeout=10
):
    try:
        return WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((by, selector))
        )
    except Exception:
        raise Exception(
            "Element {%s} was not visible/clickable after %s seconds!"
            % (selector, timeout)
        )

# ...

element = wait_for_element_clickable(driver, "button#id")
element.click()
```